# Getting ItemNotMappedException in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am running a nant script which is pulling data from TFS 2010.  It works on our build machine (which creates its own TFS session) but not on my laptop.

Instead I get an ItemNotMappedException.     The directory listed is mapped according to Visual Studio 2010.   I have tried retrieving that specific directory via VS2010 with no problems--even when I use that trick of getting specific and, within the dialog, specifying the latest version with the two check boxes checked.

I am looking for how to further troubleshoot this situation.   If it matters, I am running Win 7 Ultimate on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the NAnt script?

It should run with the same user as Visual Studio 2010.

For example, if you run Visual Studio 2010 as Administrator, run NAnt from a command prompt that is also running as the Administrator.